# inherit properties of one class to another class

Tags: css

I have A.css and imported in B.css, 
    There are few classes rotate45, rotate90, rotate135 and rotate180 in A.css
    and I would like to use them in B as

```
B.css
{        
    .roate{
    // Get properties of rotate180
    }

    @media(min-width:570)
    {
        .roate{
        // Get properties of rotate45
        }
    }

    @media(min-width:750)
    {
        .roate{
        // Get properties of rotate90
        }
    }

    @media(min-width:950)
    {
        .roate{
        // Get properties of rotate135
        }
    }

}
```

can any one help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Import `A.css` into `B.css`.

Use `@import url();` at the begining of the file.

**B.css**

```
@import url('path/to/A.css');

// code in B.css
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my requirement is after adding reference i need to inherit the classes available in A.css to B.css. for example i have a class                 as .rotate180{ color: red}, .rotate90{color:green}, and in my new file B.css i need to use them like @media(min-width:950px){ .rotate{ inherit rotate180 class from A.css  } } @media(min-width:750px){ .rotate{ inherit rotate90 class from A.css  } }.    Thanks in advance